# How to keep page loaded after first visit in Ionic Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes

I have a side menu app in Ionic Angular and for now I have the typical root navigation

```
      <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false">

        <ion-item routerDirection="root" routerLink="/map" lines="none" detail="false" routerLinkActive="selected">
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="map-sharp"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Map</ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item routerDirection="root" routerLink="/routes" lines="none" detail="false" routerLinkActive="selected">
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="navigate-circle-sharp"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Routes</ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item routerDirection="root" routerLink="/couriers" lines="none" detail="false" routerLinkActive="selected">
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="car-sharp"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Couriers</ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item routerDirection="root" routerLink="/deliveries" lines="none" detail="false" routerLinkActive="selected">
          <ion-icon slot="start" name="pin-sharp"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Deliveries</ion-label>
        </ion-item>

      </ion-menu-toggle>
```

And what I would like to do is to apply the same rules as in the TABS application where the page is lazy loaded but then it remains loaded after I navigate to other tabs.
I tried to google a lot about this but for some reason I couldn't find a concrete answer. Maybe I am just missing something

Right now I have the route configuration in app-routing.module.ts as

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'map',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'routes',
    loadChildren: () => import('./routes/routes.module').then( m => m.RoutesPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'map',
    loadChildren: () => import('./map/map.module').then( m => m.MapPageModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'couriers',
    loadChildren: () => import('./couriers/couriers.module').then( m => m.CouriersPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'deliveries',
    loadChildren: () => import('./deliveries/deliveries.module').then( m => m.DeliveriesPageModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: When you say "it remains loaded" what do you mean exactly? What problem are you trying to solve or what behavior are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @E.Maggini Exactly the same behaviour as in the <ion-tabs> component where the page does not re-initialise (a reference would be ngOnInit() which is run only once in the tabs component) as when you perform routerDirection="root/forward"

Comment: I discovered that changing this behaviour is very difficult.
I though that using a different (or custom) *Reuse Strategy* would solved all my problems but I encountered the "Not supported" (well documented in Ionic from years) issue/bug/limit. Using a custom Reuse Strategy I successfully set ALL components/pages as REUSABLE (so no ngOnInit() called more than once) but if you need at least 1 components not-reusable you need to manage its "reset" manually and it's not very easy. I think there isn't any real solution until the "Not supported" bug/limit is corrcted by Ionic Team.

Comment: @emandt Thank you very much for your reply. I am not very familiar with the Reuse Strategy but I will look into it. Also, if I understood correctly, this would be easier to implement if I just use Angular without Ionic?

Comment: I think the "Reuse Strategy" is nearly the same so I'm not very sure you would solve this via Angular. All my Components (in a Ionic App or in an Web-Angular App never mantains their state after ngOnDestroy(), so....)

Comment: @emandt I understand. What about the ion-tabs component, do you think they use the same reuse strategy for it? If yes, maybe it s worth analysing why that one works with other non reusable pages or components